# 'Have the ability to quickly adapt with changing technologies'. Is this a grammatically correct construction?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I'd like to know whether the preposition "with" is the best choice after the verb "adapt".

Comment: For starts, it's not a sentence. Sentences have subjects. This is a verb phrase. As for the preposition, _adapt_ is used with _to_ when using an object like _changing technologies_. To say _adapt with_ instead of _adapt to_ is to treat the changing technologies as context one grows with, rather than methods one adopts in order to make things.

Comment: ***adapt to*** changing technologies. https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/adapt+to

Comment: @JohnLawler Are imperatives sentences? e.g. "Tell me!"

Comment: Yes, but this isn't an imperative, since _have_ in the sense of 'possess' is a stative verb, and they can't occur in imperatives.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to write a resume judging by the sentence fragment.

In any case, you adapt to changes, not with them.

Comment: Thank you Arunkgp, for your answer. Yes, I was trying to add texts in my CV. Thanaks again for the answer. surely, it helped me.